# Unable to understand elasticsearch analyser regex

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers

Can someone help me understand why my understanding of an elasticsearch analyser is wrong?

I have an index containing various fields, one in particular is:

```
"categories": {
    "type": "text",
    "analyzer": "words_only_analyser",
    "copy_to": "all",
    "fields": {
         "tokens": {
             "type": "text",
             "analyzer": "words_only_analyser",
             "term_vector": "yes",
             "fielddata" : True
          }
      }
}
```

The `words_only_analyser` looks like:

```
"words_only_analyser":{
    "type":"custom",
    "tokenizer":"words_only_tokenizer",
    "char_filter" : ["html_strip"],
    "filter":[ "lowercase", "asciifolding", "stop_filter", "kstem" ]
},
```

and the `words_only_tokenizer` looks like:

```
"tokenizer":{
    "words_only_tokenizer":{
    "type":"pattern",
    "pattern":"[^\\w-]+"
    }
}
```

My understanding of the `pattern` `[^\\w-]+` in `tokenizer` is that it will tokenize a sentence such that it splits them at any number of occurrence of `\` or `w` or `-`. For example, given the pattern, a sentence of:

```
seasonal-christmas-halloween this is a description about halloween
```

I expect to see:

```
[seasonal, christmas, hallo, een this is a description about hallo, een]
```

I can confirm the above from https://regex101.com/

However, when I run `words_only_analyser` on the sentence above:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/contextual/_analyze?pretty -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"analyzer":"words_only_analyser","text":"seasonal-christmas-halloween this is a description about halloween"}'
```

I get,

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "seasonal-christmas-halloween",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 28,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "description",
      "start_offset" : 39,
      "end_offset" : 50,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 4
    },
    {
      "token" : "halloween",
      "start_offset" : 57,
      "end_offset" : 66,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 6
    }
  ]
}
```

This tells me the sentence gets tokenized to:

```
[seasonal-christmas-halloween, description, halloween]
```

It appears to me the tokenizer pattern is not being fulfilled? Can someone explain to me where my understanding is incorrect?

Comment: Did you mean any non-alphanumeric and non-hyphen? Try `"pattern":"[^0-9A-Za-z-]+"`

Comment: This is an existing source code I'm looking at, so I'm just trying to understand what is happening.

Comment: @Mark did you get a chance to look at my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things, which is changing the final tokens produced by your analyzer, first is the tokenizer and after that the token-filters(for ex:you have stop_filter that removes the stop words like `this`, `is`, `a`).

you can use the analyze API to test your `tokenizer` as well, I created your configuration and it produces below tokens.

POST _analyze

```
{
    "tokenizer": "words_only_tokenizer", // Note `tokenizer` here
    "text": "seasonal-christmas-halloween this is a description about halloween"
}
```

Result

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "seasonal-christmas-halloween",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 28,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "this",
            "start_offset": 29,
            "end_offset": 33,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "is",
            "start_offset": 34,
            "end_offset": 36,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 2
        },
        {
            "token": "a",
            "start_offset": 37,
            "end_offset": 38,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 3
        },
        {
            "token": "description",
            "start_offset": 39,
            "end_offset": 50,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 4
        },
        {
            "token": "about",
            "start_offset": 51,
            "end_offset": 56,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 5
        },
        {
            "token": "halloween",
            "start_offset": 57,
            "end_offset": 66,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 6
        }
    ]
}
```

You can notice, still stop words are present, as its just breaking the tokens on whitespace and not considering `-`.

Now if you run same on `analyzer` which also has `filters`, it would reduce the `stop words` and gives you below tokens.

POST _analyze

```
{
    "analyzer": "words_only_analyser",
    "text": "seasonal-christmas-halloween this is a description about halloween"
}
```

**Result**

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "seasonal-christmas-halloween",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 28,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "description",
            "start_offset": 39,
            "end_offset": 50,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 4
        },
        {
            "token": "about",
            "start_offset": 51,
            "end_offset": 56,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 5
        },
        {
            "token": "halloween",
            "start_offset": 57,
            "end_offset": 66,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 6
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Not sure if you're able to answer this, as you can see there is a ```copy_to``` in ```categories```. When it gets copied to ```all``` I know what gets copied across is the untokenised version. So by default when it's in ```all```, does it get tokenised by the default method ```standard```? I think it does but I can't find docs on it

Comment: @Mark Yes, It will get tokenised by the tokeniser used by _all field or custom all field, the documentation doesn't say this explicitly but it does say -> "It is the field value which is copied, not the terms (which result from the analysis process)." , so once the field value gets copied, further it will be analyzed by all field analyser, standard in most cases.